# What's the right way of writing the following code?

Tags: php, html, arrays, if-statement, get

Is it possible to output a certain link from a certain collection via a URL parameter like: https://www.example.com/test/index.php?col=1&number=6 (this should output the 6th link from Collection 1) and so on?

```php
<?php
$col = $_GET['collection'];
$number = $_GET['link_number'];
}

if $col = 1 & $number = 1 { echo "My link 1" }
if $col = 1 & $number = 2 { echo "My link 2" }
if $col = 1 & $number = 3 { echo "My link 3" }
if $col = 1 & $number = 4 { echo "My link 4" }
if $col = 1 & $number = 5 { echo "My link 5" }
if $col = 1 & $number = 6 { echo "My link 6" }
if $col = 1 & $number = 7 { echo "My link 7" }
if $col = 1 & $number = 8 { echo "My link 8" }
if $col = 1 & $number = 9 { echo "My link 9" }
if $col = 1 & $number = 10 { echo "My link 10" }

if $col = 2 & $number = 1 { echo "My link 1" }
if $col = 2 & $number = 2 { echo "My link 2" }
if $col = 2 & $number = 3 { echo "My link 3" }
if $col = 2 & $number = 4 { echo "My link 4" }
if $col = 2 & $number = 5 { echo "My link 5" }
if $col = 2 & $number = 6 { echo "My link 6" }
if $col = 2 & $number = 7 { echo "My link 7" }
if $col = 2 & $number = 8 { echo "My link 8" }
if $col = 2 & $number = 9 { echo "My link 9" }
if $col = 2 & $number = 10 { echo "My link 10" }
?>
```

Comment: This is a code review question. But I would do an if col == 1 and open a {} inside that I would have if number ==... That would make it little easier to read and write.

Comment: Use a 2 dimensions array to store your links and just use `echo $collection[$column][$number]`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a code review question. Post the question there instead. SO is for non working code.

Comment: you are not using semi colons after php statements also

Answer (score 1):

Please use multidimensional array to store collection of urls. This will help you.

```
   <?php
    $col = $_GET['collection'];
    $number = $_GET['link_number'];
    $collection_urls = [1=> [1=>"url1", 2=>"url2"], 2 => [1=>"url1" , 2=>"url2"]]

    echo "My link ".$collection_urls[$col][$number].PHP_EOL; 

    ?>
```

Comment: Do you really think it's "My link" that should be the output? Don't you just think that is a placeholder for the question?

Comment: @Andreas I answered according to the code he has given. Changed the code again.